# About the flatness of a countable infinite direct product

Tags: commutative-algebra, flatness

By the work of Stephen U. Chase [Direct products of modules. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 97 (1960), 457-473]. For a commutative domain A, the direct product of any family of copies of A is flat as A-module if and only if A is a coherent domain (that is: the intersection of two finitely generated ideal of A is finitely generated). 
My question is: Can we find a commutative domain A which is not coherent and such that the A-module $A^{\mathbb{N}}$ is A-flat?